# how can i create nice image slide show like facebook or flick

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slideshow, image-gallery

i have created a website with  images. how can i create nice image slide show  which i click on picture Facebook or Flickr.  is there any free jQuery / Ajax i can use. ??   at the minute i am using Galleria libraries. it works fine but i need to pass exta parameters form main page ( which has all the images ) to slide show page .

link for Galleria
http://galleria.io/docs/getting_started/beginners_guide/#complete-code

is there an other libraries i can use for  image slide show .

Comment: There's loads . do a google search

Answer (score 0):

Flexslider is good because its responsive and handy enough to implement. Uses jQuery as well though